# panic: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/secrets/kubernetes-dashboard-csrf: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout

Tags: kubernetes

When I deploy kubernetes v1.16.0 dashboard `kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.0.0`, it throws this error:

```
[miaoyou@MeowK8SMaster1 ~]$ kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-56484d4c5-7jcvh -n kubernetes-dashboard
2020/06/14 06:47:33 Starting overwatch
2020/06/14 06:47:33 Using namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
2020/06/14 06:47:33 Using in-cluster config to connect to apiserver
2020/06/14 06:47:33 Using secret token for csrf signing
2020/06/14 06:47:33 Initializing csrf token from kubernetes-dashboard-csrf secret
panic: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/secrets/kubernetes-dashboard-csrf: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/csrf.(*csrfTokenManager).init(0xc00000d540)
    /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/csrf/manager.go:41 +0x446
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/csrf.NewCsrfTokenManager(...)
    /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/csrf/manager.go:66
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client.(*clientManager).initCSRFKey(0xc00048e880)
    /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/manager.go:501 +0xc6
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client.(*clientManager).init(0xc00048e880)
    /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/manager.go:469 +0x47
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client.NewClientManager(...)
    /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/manager.go:550
main.main()
    /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/dashboard.go:105 +0x20d
```

The kubernetes cluster running fine before I tweak the token `ttl` time.

[image]

After I tweak `ttl` time, restart throw this error.How to fix this problem?

```
[miaoyou@MeowK8SMaster1 ~]$ kubectl get pods -n kubernetes-dashboard -o wide
NAME                                        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE             NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
dashboard-metrics-scraper-c79c65bb7-5bgrw   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   3569       8d    10.244.0.3   meowk8smaster1   <none>           <none>
kubernetes-dashboard-56484d4c5-7jcvh        0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   13         51m   10.244.0.6   meowk8smaster1   <none>           <none>




[miaoyou@MeowK8SMaster1 ~]$ curl -k https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/secrets/kubernetes-dashboard-csrf
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "secrets \"kubernetes-dashboard-csrf\" is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get resource \"secrets\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"kubernetes-dashboard\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "name": "kubernetes-dashboard-csrf",
    "kind": "secrets"
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

Comment: how do you change token til time? What do you restart after  that? share output of kubectl get pods -n kube-system

Comment: try editing via kubectl -n kube-system edit deployments kubernetes-dashboard and add - --token-ttl=43200